# Assetic dump for prod mode doesn't work

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I am using assetic for my assets management (see [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)). My colleague which I am developing together runs this command to dump the assets

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

which works fine. But when I run this command I get this output

```
$ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.

14:35:51 [file+] C:/path/to/myapp/app/../web/js/c49cee5.js

<compressed file contents ...>
```

followed by all the compressed JavaScript code. I mean this is displayed on my screen instead of dumping it into a file. This does not happen at my colleagues machine.

Note:

- My colleague is running Max OSX, I am running Windows 7.
- There is no problem with not finding Java.
- Assets are dumped, when running command for dev environment.

Comment: Does it give an error at the start of the dumped code, possibly java not being found not being found or something of that kind? The Symfony docs say about Windows `Windows users need to remember to update config to proper java location. In Windows7 x64 bit by default it's C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe.` so that may help.

Comment: No there is no error about Java. Actually when I run the assetic dump command for dev environment there is no error. Only for prod env.

Comment: Show your assetic configuration, please.

Comment: Also assetic is set to `use_controllers` by default in `config_dev.yml` so it might not be doing any kind of actual dumping.

Comment: @Qoop no that is not the problem, I deactivated that but error remains.

Comment: Ziumin: See config files (excerpt) here https://gist.github.com/dialogik/988b599c180a13ef1c91